# How to add a hyperlink to a cell in a worksheet using office-js without using hyperlink fomula?

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm currently using the latest version of ExcelApi, and was able to add a hyperlink formula by specifying the following (simplified) code:

```js
var firstCellInSelection = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange().getCell(0, 0);
firstCellInSelection.formulas = [['=HYPERLINK("http://www.bing.com")']];
```

What I would like to do, however, is replicate Excel's "Insert > Link" functionality, which simply adds the hyperlink into the cell *without* using a formula.

(FYI the reason I want to do this is, I want to subsequently use openXML to iterate through all the hyperlinks in an Excel file, but this unfortunately excludes the =hyperlink formulas...)

PS: In WordApi, I was able to do just this using **range.hyperlink**.

Does anyone have any idea how to get the same behavior in ExcelApi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This funcionality isn't supported in the ExcelApi v1.6 but it is coming in ExcelApi v1.7 ([currently in beta](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/ExcelJs_OpenSpec/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets.md)).

You can read about the new [RangeHyperlink](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/ExcelJs_OpenSpec/reference/excel/rangehyperlink.md) object in the beta documentation.

Comment: Thanks Marc, that's what I was afraid of but I wanted to make sure... Do you have an estimation on when ExcelApi v1.7 will become available to Office365?

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out samples available in Script Lab (developer platground add-in, you can search and install through the store). If you look under "Preview APIs", you'll find "Range Hyperlinks" sample that shows how to add/update/remove hyperlinks. Once we move this API to GA, the sample will appear under Range functions of Script Lab samples.